# Get file content of uploaded file using java script in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an app for android using phone gap in which i am providing the feature of file uploading and i want to read the content of uploaded file and encode it to base64 and stored it to localStorage.
I am using Filereader to read the content but its not work in app

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var content = evt.target.result;
        file_content = btoa(content);
        alert(file_content);
        var nameContent = name + "," + file_content;
        localStorage.setItem("contentFile" + i, Encryptdata(nameContent.toString()));
        count++;
    }
};
```

in my app reader.onload not executing.

Comment: Try using `onloadend` instead.

Comment: i tried with onloadend but still not executing,any other options are there? or can i read the full path of uploaded file?

Comment: hi is this issue solved? i m facing the same. please if you have find solution the tell please